# How to find the frquency of items in a given dataframe considering specific subgroups?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes: `df1`

```
groups = {'Items': ["a", "b", "c", "c", "d", "d", "x", "y", "z", "p", "q", "m", "a", "b", "c", "d", "y", "z", "o", "d"],
          'Groups': ["c11d", "c11d", "c22c", "c22c", "c22c", "c22c", "dp1", "dp1", "dp3", "dp3", "dp1", "dp1", "lp1",
                    "lp2", "lp2", "lp2", "lp1", "lp1", "rk1", "rk1"],
          'Tags': ["banana", "banana", "banana", "banana", "banana", "banana", "orange", "orange", "orange", "orange",
                   "orange", "orange", "lemon", "lemon", "lemon", "lemon", "lemon", "lemon", "apple", "apple"]
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(groups)
```

df1

```
    Items   Groups  Tags
0   a       c11d    banana
1   b       c11d    banana
2   c       c22c    banana
3   c       c22c    banana
4   d       c22c    banana
5   d       c22c    banana
6   x       dp1     orange
7   y       dp1     orange
8   z       dp3     orange
9   p       dp3     orange
10  q       dp1     orange
11  m       dp1     orange
12  a       lp1     lemon
13  b       lp2     lemon
14  c       lp2     lemon
15  d       lp2     lemon
16  y       lp1     lemon
17  z       lp1     lemon
18  o       rk1     apple
19  d       rk1     apple
```

then `df2`

```
terms = {'Groups': ["banana", "apple", "orange", "lemon"],
          '1C': ["a,b,c,d", "b,d,z,y", "c,x,y,p", "p,q"],
          '2C': ["m,n,a", "o,c,d", "p,r,d", ""]
}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(terms)
```

df2

```
    Groups  1C        2C
0   banana  a,b,c,d   m,n,a
1   apple   b,d,z,y   o,c,d
2   orange  c,x,y,p   p,r,d
3   lemon   p,q
```

I want to map items of each column of `df2` based on `Groups` to the other dataframe `df1` and find the frequency of tags by items in `df2` which is subdivided by groups.

The expected output is:

```
Groups  1C      1C.Freq         2C      2C.Freq
banana  a,b,c,d c11d=2, c22c=4  m,n,a   c11d=1, c22c=0
apple   b,d,z,y rk1=1           o,c,d   rk1=2
orange  c,x,y,p dp1=2, dp3=1    p,r,d   dp1=0, dp3=1
lemon   p,q,z   lp1=1,lp2=0             lp1=0,lp2=0
```

Sorry for my langugage. Any help appreciated. Thanks :)
The real dataframe has more tags and columns.

Comment: maybe I am wrong but you are getting wrong values in your expected output

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a function to compute the frequencies for a given column (`1C` or `2C`):

```py
def freq(col):
    df = df1.merge(df2[['Groups', col]], how='left', left_on='Tags', right_on='Groups')
    
    # convert comma-separated values -> lists -> rows
    df[col] = df[col].str.split(',')
    df = df.explode(col)
    
    # mark and count the matches
    df['match'] = df['Items'] == df[col]
    df = df.groupby(['Tags', 'Groups_x'])['match'].sum().reset_index()

    # format the matches as 'key=value'
    df[f'{col}.Freq'] = df.pop('Groups_x') + '=' + df.pop('match').astype(str)
    
    # combine the matches per group as 'key1=value2,key2=value2,...'
    return df.groupby('Tags').agg(','.join).reindex(df2['Groups'])
```

Either add the frequency columns to the end of `df2`:

```py
df2['1C.Freq'] = freq('1C').values
df2['2C.Freq'] = freq('2C').values

#    Groups       1C     2C        1C.Freq        2C.Freq
# 0  banana  a,b,c,d  m,n,a  c11d=2,c22c=4  c11d=1,c22c=0
# 1   apple  b,d,z,y  o,c,d          rk1=1          rk1=2
# 2  orange  c,x,y,p  p,r,d    dp1=2,dp3=1    dp1=0,dp3=1
# 3   lemon      p,q           lp1=0,lp2=0    lp1=0,lp2=0
```

Or use [`DataFrame.insert`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) to put them in the exact order of your OP:

```py
df2.insert(2, '1C.F', freq('1C').values)
df2.insert(4, '2C.F', freq('2C').values)

#    Groups       1C           1C.F     2C           2C.F
# 0  banana  a,b,c,d  c11d=2,c22c=4  m,n,a  c11d=1,c22c=0
# 1   apple  b,d,z,y          rk1=1  o,c,d          rk1=2
# 2  orange  c,x,y,p    dp1=2,dp3=1  p,r,d    dp1=0,dp3=1
# 3   lemon      p,q    lp1=0,lp2=0           lp1=0,lp2=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Merge both the dataframes, renaming the Tag, and Groups columns from first dataframe to Groups, and SubGroups respectively, then filter out the first dataframe and perfroma grouping and aggregation, same thing for the second dataframe, finally concatenate both of  them.

```py
from collections import Counter
merged=df1.rename(columns={'Tags':'Groups', 'Groups':'SubGroups'}).merge(df2)
first=(merged[merged.apply(lambda x: x['Items'] in x['1C'], axis=1)].
       groupby('Groups', sort=False).
       agg({'1C':'first', 'SubGroups':Counter}).
       rename(columns={'SubGroups':'1C.Freq'})
      )
second=(merged[merged.apply(lambda x: x['Items'] in x['2C'], axis=1)].
        groupby('Groups', sort=False).
        agg({'2C':'first', 'SubGroups':Counter}).
        rename(columns={'SubGroups':'2C.Freq'}
              )
pd.concat([first, second], axis=1)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
         1C         1C.Freq              2C     2C.Freq
Groups              
banana  a,b,c,d {'c11d': 2, 'c22c': 4}  m,n,a   {'c11d': 1}
orange  c,x,y,p {'dp1': 2, 'dp3': 1}    p,r,d   {'dp3': 1}
apple   b,d,z,y {'rk1': 1}              o,c,d   {'rk1': 2}
```

**PS:** I suggest you to use dictionary for the frequency columns since you will be able to easily use it later.

Comment: but in this code: the data is lost: `lemon   p,q                     lp1=3,lp2=3     lp1=3,lp2=3`